# programmatically import unit test results from xml into Junit view in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to programmatically import unit test results from xml file into Junit view in IntelliJ.
This code opens file but only into the text editor.

```
    Project project = ProjectManager.getInstance().getOpenProjects()[0];

    File fileIO = new File("E:\\Work\\Sandbox2\\src\\test\\resources\\file.xml");
    VirtualFile file = LocalFileSystem.getInstance().findFileByIoFile(fileIO);
    OpenFileDescriptor descriptor = new OpenFileDescriptor(project, file);
    descriptor.navigate(true);
```

Any suggestion how to modify code to get what I want ?

Comment: You can't modify this code, you need to write a completely different implementation which would be approximately 100x as much code (not an exaggeration). The JUnit view in IntelliJ IDEA does not work by parsing XML files, so you'll need to write your own logic for parsing XML and filling the JUnit tree model with your data.

Comment: Thanks, 
"The JUnit view in IntelliJ IDEA does not work by parsing XML files " 
So how is it possible that I can import test results from xml into the view ?
The action is "Import From File ..." . Did you mean that there is no API for this ?

Comment: Ah, then it's not that bad. You can look at the implementation of the import action here: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/smRunner/src/com/intellij/execution/testframework/sm/runner/history/actions/AbstractImportTestsAction.java

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful.